# Agregar nueva fila a un Gridview Devexpress con datos de una consulta SQL

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

La mecánica es la siguiente, doy clic en un `button` y traigo unos datos a mi BD, algunos de estos los debo agregar a una grilla pero como una nueva fila es decir que puedo se[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]leccionar otros `button` y sigo agregando.

Es un menu y se selecciona el producto, datos como el nombre, precio y cantidad deben ser cargados en la grilla, he intentado de muchas maneras pero no me da, por favor alguien que me colabore...... :(

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar filas al gridview no tienes mas que crear un DataTable cargado desde la base de datos y asignarlo a la propiedad DataSource del grid

```
Dim tabla as DataTable
tabla = DB.GetDataTable("select..")
grid.DataSource = tabla
grid.DataBind()
```

si puedes poner mas información de como estas sacando datos de la bd sería mejor